# AFNetworking crashing in multilingual app

Tags: ios, afnetworking, multilingual

> Ride[source_name]=2152,%20Mohali%20Stadium%20Rd,%20Phase%2010,%20Sector%2064,%20Sahibzada%20Ajit%20Singh%20Nagar,%20Punjab%20160062,%20भारत

This parameter is causing crash while running in Hindi while working fine with Spanish and English. Please suggest me on it. Crash description is as following:-

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: URLString'
>
> ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with this

**Objective - C**

```
NSString *string = @"भारत";
NSString *encoded = [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let string = "भारत"
let urlString = string.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: . urlUserAllowed)
```

> Output :: %E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4

Answer (score 1):

Add below line of code to avoid invalid parameters in url.

```
NSString *str = ...; // Your URL
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]; 
NSString *result = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];
```

**Deprecated Code Before ios 9.0 :**

```
NSString *str = ...; // Your URL
NSString *urlAsString = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is deprecated in iOS 9+

Comment: u r rite @shahrukhshikalgar. I have updated my answer